# Cross class invoke in Thor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, thor

I am trying to invoke thor class from another thor class.

```
class Foo < Thor
  desc "hello", "some description"
  def hello
    puts "Hello from Foo class"
  end
end

class Bar < Thor
desc "hello", "some description"
  def hello
    puts "Hello from Bar class"
    # ==> HERE I WANT TO CALL HELLO FROM FOO CLASS <==
  end
end
```

There is invoke method but to call methods inside same class. Is there a way to do this cross-class? I am assuming the proper way would use Thor framework.

**EDIT**

I am trying to have one class that delegates task to other classes. For example you call `foo bar list`, and main class Foo delegates to Bar class with method list, or `foo module find 1`, and deligates to Module class with method find and arguments 1.

Comment: Is there a Thor-specific reason you can't put the method in a superclass? Otherwise you'd need an instance, or as you said there might be a Thor-way to not have to follow normal Ruby semantics/usage.

Comment: Added more info above, point being is I have a lot of thor classes and I want to give them prefix command. Which would go to this main class and delegate to others. I was wondering if there was Thor like practice to do this.

Answer (score 2):

i never used Thor, but i think that from having a look at the spec here https://github.com/wycats/thor/blob/master/spec/invocation_spec.rb

it would be

```
Foo.new.invoke(:hello)
```